# Action Listeners

Tags: java, listener, action

I have rows and columns of jbuttons, and when each button is clicked they should turn red, and when clicked a second time they should return to their original color. So far, the code I have written is as follows:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel
{

    private JButton[][] btn1 = new JButton[3][5];

    public MainPanel() 
    {
        JPanel MainPanel= new JPanel();
        MainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,700));

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        {
            p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,5,10,10));
            p1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    btn1[i][j] = new JButton();
                    btn1[i][j].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    p1.add(btn1[i][j]);

                    btn1[i][j].addActionListener
                    (
                        new ActionListener() 
                        {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                            {
                                btn1[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The line `btn1[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);` is stating 'local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final'. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add listeners in loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        final JButton btn = btn1[i][j];
        btn1[i][j].addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

You added listener only to the first button.

Comment: Putting it inside the for loop flags up the line

        btn1[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);

saying 'local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final, and does not work

Comment: Define the btn1 variable as final.

Comment: @paco Panel p1 is located inside a main panel. In the main panel i have declared the btn1 variable here, see the edited question for a view. The line btn1[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED); is still not working.

Comment: @pato the line btn1[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED); has the part 'setBackground' underlined and says that it 'cannot find symbol

Comment: @May please look at my updated answer. Especially those lines: final JButton btn = btn1[i][j]; btn.setBackground(Color.RED);